# Adding a [jsons] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I attempted to create a new tag with a SO post. This new tag is about the Python [jsons](https://pypi.org/project/jsons/) library. Not a super popular library (with 43 stars as of this post) but still I feel is a valid tag to have.

When I attempted to implicitly create the tag I was told to open a discussion here.

[image]

I believe this tag is valid and should exist even with the similarity to the `json` tag.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The tag [jsons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsons) would be too similar to the present [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) tag, which would result in a lot of people mistagging their questions.

Using [python-jsons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-jsons) would be a better idea here.

There certainly would be a few questions about using JSON in Python, which would  wrongly be tagged as [python-jsons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-jsons). We cannot really help much in those cases, apart from manually retagging the questions as they crop up. The issue here is the name of the library which is too similar to JSON.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and seems like a sensible solution.

I don't think a lot of retagging will need to happen but I do believe that might change in the future. The library attempts to solve a pretty fundamental lack in the Python json standard library that gets searched on SO decently often. I personally suspect that the primary reason it's not widely used is because it's a python3 only library.

Comment: etiquette question: Should the person who asked for the tag make the agreed upon one or the person who answered the question make the tag? Does it matter?

Comment: We should actually wait until there is enough community consensus (about a day or two). After that it doesn't matter who creates the tag.

Comment: To minimize the all too likely user mistakes, wouldn't a more explicit name like "`python-jsons-library`", to attempt making it more obvious it's about a concrete library and not about "deal with JSON using Python"?

Comment: Yep, that sounds fine too @yivi. Or perhaps [python-jsons-package] to keep it different from the [builtin python json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). However, I wonder if that'd make the tag name obscured, and that people wouldn't use the tag much.

Comment: @yivi - I would just stick with `python-jsons`. Most libraries do *not* have a tag ending in `-library`; most packages do *not* have a tag ending in `-package`. There is no need to further disambiguate `python-jsons`. A question about JSON in Python should be tagged with `python` and with `json`.

Comment: @JohnY most libraries and packages do not have such generic names, and thus less need for disambiguation; IMO.

Comment: @yivi - "jsons" is already distinct from "json". Once you put `python-` in front of it, you have also eliminated virtually any chance of accidentally mistyping the tag that you are really interested in.

Comment: My point is that it is similar enough to lend itself to confusion. But I see that you disagree, and it’s fine.

Comment: As for the [*etiquette question*](/q/386372/#comment705486_386373) raised by @AlexLordThorsen: it actually does make a difference who creates the tag, because this is essential for earning the [Taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge. IMO, OP should create the tag whatever the final name will be.

Comment: Would it be fair to state that `python-jsons` is the accepted tag at this point?

Comment: Yes, I'd assume so, @AlexLordThorsen

Comment: The "tag too obscure" isn't a problem, since the tag field uses fuzzy search to suggest tags. So, writing jsons, would show the pre/sufixed tag.